# Oracle compile package: table has errors

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, dblink

I have a big problem on my database.

I have a Oracle 9i database and a Oracle 11g database.

I have a package with a stored procedure on my 9i database. Inside  a have a very simple select like :

```
select * from my_table_on_my_11g_database@MYDBLINK;
```

When I'm trying to compile the package containing this query, I have the following error :

```
[Error] ORA-04063 (337: 20): PL/SQL: ORA-04063: table "my_table_on_my_11g_database" has errors
```

When I'm trying to execute the query using Toad in a editor, it works fine.
So, I don't know what is the problem. 
It's about roles, rights ?

We just installed this 11G database, before we had a 9i database and it worked fine. I'm guessing I'm missing some grants ?

Thanks for any idea.

C.C.

Comment: [`ORA-04063:  table/view has errors`](http://psoug.org/oraerror/ORA-04063.htm)

**Cause**:  Attempt to execute a stored procedure or use a view that has errors.  For stored procedures, the problem could be syntax errors or references to other, non-existent procedures.    For views,  the problem could be a reference in the view's defining query to a non-existent table.  Can also be a table which has references to non-existent or inaccessible types.  

**Action**: Fix the errors and/or create referenced objects as necessary.

Comment: There are no error on my table.  When I execute the same select in a sql editor, it works.

Comment: Have you checked that the dblink is set up in the new database to correctly point at the same place as in the old one? Is Toad connecting to the same database or is it still connecting to the old database?

Comment: the database that changed is the 11g one. My package is on my 9i that is unchanged.

Comment: are you running the standalone query with the same user that you are using to compile the program? Also, is the DBlink private or public ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally it works. I've created a new public DBLink  and it works.
It was maybe because the DBLInk was created before with the old database, I don't know.
Thanks for the answers.